# How to access the name of ActiveX controls in Word by OLE Automation in C++

Tags: c++, ms-word, office-automation

How to access the name of ActiveX controls in Word by OLE Automation in C++

Visiting all ActiveX controls by OLE Automation and collecting their names is an easy task in C#.
It just requires to add the COM references for Word and for Microsoft Forms and you can iterating the `Shapes` or `InlineShapes`.
`OLEFormat.Object` gives you access to the ActiveX control and the member `name` contains its name in Word.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Forms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;

static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open("sample.docm");

    foreach (Word.Shape shape in doc.Shapes)
    {
        String name = shape.OLEFormat.Object.name;
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

The question is how to do this in c++. It is possible to use the typelib for Word and get the `Shapes`, access their `OLEFormat` and finally the `Object`. This `Object` seems not be represented in
the Word or the Forms typelib at all. It seems to be an abstract class for all kind of ActiveX controls. The question is, how to access the 'name' from it. Also the ActiveX controls like `ComboBox` do not contain a property `name`.

So the question is how to solve this by C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Object` is not represented in the typelib for Word or for Forms, but `IDispatch::Invoke` can be used to query for `name`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).